# BigQuery - DateTime gives unexpected time differences when converting from UTC to CET

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Right now it's 02:00 give or take in Stockholm (CET). Which is 00:00 UTC according to Google search and various websites.

Why then does:

```
  SELECT DATETIME("2021-04-12 00:00:24.608 UTC","CET")  -- Adds two hours (expected)
```

Only add 2 hours (as expected), however:

```
  SELECT DATETIME("2021-03-13 14:51:24.608 UTC","CET") -- Returns 15:51 instead of 16:51??
```

.. only adds ONE hour?

Is this a bug or am I missing something like daylight savings? I was under the impression that there's always a constant 2 hour difference between the timezones all year around.

Right now I've reverted to using

```
 DATETIME_ADD(DATETIME(ts), INTERVAL 2 HOUR) -- Manually adding +2 hours
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of the summer time: Sweden switches from "winter time" (UTC+1H) to "summer time" (UTC+2H) on the last Sunday of March for daylight savings, see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_European_Summer_Time).

The conversion offered by BigQuery here is totally correct.

Sweden then goes back to "winter time" on the last Sunday of October.

Comment: Thakns, UTC doesn't have daylight savings, therefore my confusion